# Make sure to get different results for two workers on a PostgresqlDB

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, locking

I have a PostgresDB and in one table I have Server-IPs, now I want to take a bunch of workers to go and check the servers in my DBs. But I want to make sure that no two workers get the same Server-IP, so as soon as one IP is selected it should be unavailable for all the other workers.

```
CREATE TABLE server
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    created INTEGER NOT NULL,
    modified INTEGER NOT NULL
)

Sampledata
1 | 192.168.5.22 | 1476086120 | 1476086120
2 | 192.168.5.29 | 1476084147 | 1476084147

Worker 1: SELECT ip FROM server LIMIT 1 -> 192.168.5.22
Worker 2: SELECT ip FROM server LIMIT 1 -> 192.168.5.22   // but I'd rather have the result for id = 2 here, since id = 1 was already selected by Worker 1
```

Can anyone please point me into a good direction on how to achieve this?

The regular locking won't do, as far as I can tell, since it only applies to Insert, Update, Delete and all I do is Select.

Maybe there is a way of selecting and updating in one step, but I haven't found anything relating to that.
So some help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add the table definitions (as `create table` statements) some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `UPDATE ... RETURNING` as in the following example:

```
UPDATE iptable
SET processed = TRUE
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM iptable
             WHERE NOT processed
             LIMIT 1)
RETURNING ip_adress;
```

Here `id` is the primary key.
A partial index `ON iptable(id) WHERE NOT processed` may speed up the query.

Alternatively, you can use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and `UPDATE` in one transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id
FROM iptable
WHERE NOT processed
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE iptable SET processed = TRUE WHERE id = ...;

COMMIT;
```